# Why variance is only defined for square integrable random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, variance

I'm learning probability theory alone so I'm having basic questions.

Every book I read defined variance only for square integrable random variable. **So my question is:** why they exclude the case when a random variable is only integrable?

If $X$ is an integrable random variable, then $(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2$ is a non-negative measurable function and, therefore, it's Lebesgue integrable. Hence, we could define the variance of an integrable random variable $X$ as $\text{var(X)}:=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]$. In this case we still have properties such as

- $\text{Var}(aX+b)=a^2\text{Var}(X)$
- $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|\geq t)\leq \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{t^2}$ for all $t\in(0,\infty)$ using the "generalized" Chebyshev's Inequality (see the section "[Measure-theoretic statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)" in Wikipedia's article about the Chebyshev's Inequality).

Comment: Hint: $V[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$

Comment: Lebesgue integration does not handle "improper" integrals. If $X$ is integrable but not square integrable, $\Bbb E[(X-\Bbb E[X])^2]$ doesn't exist. If $X$ is not even integrable, then $\Bbb E[X]$ doesn't exist

Comment: @FShrike Lebesgue integral of non-negative measurable function is always well-defined. So $\mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]$ always exists if $X$ is integrable but its value can be $+\infty$.

Comment: @Snoop But does every important result involving variance depend on this formula?

Comment: I think it's just simpler to keep the discussion limited to the square integrable r.v.s. If $X\notin L^2$, then its variance is infinite, so the variance is not a useful quantity to keep track of for $X$. For example, the properties you mentioned in your post still hold, but only because the right-hand sides are infinite. So we don't gain anything by allowing $X\notin L^2$ into the discussion.

Comment: Sure, you could define $Var(X) = \infty$ if $X$ is integrable but not square integrable, but what would be the value of these statements if $Var(X) = \infty$?  The first is just $\infty = \infty$, and the second is $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}[X]| \ge t) \le \infty$.

Comment: By "exist" I intended, exist as a finite quantity. Infinite variance, I'd guess, is generally pathological and we want to avoid that

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Could you please explain why the variance of $X$ is infinite is X isn’t square integrable?

Comment: See the comment by @Snoop for why the variance of $X$ is infinite if $X$ isn't square integrable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any random variable $X$, you can consider the extended definition
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(X):=\inf_{s\in\Bbb{R}}\Bbb{E}[(X-s)^2].
\end{align}
This is a well-defined number in $[0,\infty]$, and it measures how far away (in the $L^2$ sense) your random variable is from the "best possible constant" (due to the infimum). If this quantity is $\infty$, then it means in particular (taking $s=0$) that $X\notin L^2$. If this quantity is finite, then there is an $s_0\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $X-s_0\in L^2$, so by virtue of constant functions $s_0$ being in $L^2$ (since we're on a probability space), it follows that $X\in L^2$, and hence $X\in L^1$, so you can expand $\Bbb{E}[(X-s)^2]=\Bbb{E}[X^2]-2s\Bbb{E}(X)+s^2$, and this quadratic can be minimized as usual to find that the best value of $s$ is indeed the mean $\Bbb{E}(X)$ (again, this makes sense since $X-s_0\in L^2\implies X\in L^2\implies X\in L^1$).

With this definition (and the standard measure theory convention that $0\cdot \infty=0$) you can indeed prove the the first equality of your post by a simple case work ($X\in L^2$ vs $X\notin L^2$, and in the latter case consider separately $a=0$ vs $a\neq 0$ if you really want to convince yourself). The inequality you write down is trivially true if $X\notin L^2$, because then the RHS of the estimate is $\infty$.

But now comes the obvious fact, also mentioned in the comments, that just because something is true, it doesn't mean it is useful. As a result, we restrict to $X\in L^2$ so that we make non-trivial statements involving the variance (but anyway, I think some texts define straight away $\text{Var}(X)=\Bbb{E}[X^2]-\Bbb{E}[X]^2$, this would only make sense if the stuff on the right makes sense... and if for instance $\Bbb{E}[X^2]=\Bbb{E}[X]^2=\infty$, the subtraction wouldn't even be well-defined. As such they take the simpler route of just assuming $X\in L^2$ from the beginning so they deal with arithmetic in $\Bbb{R}$ only. But with the "more general" definition of variance above, it makes sense in $[0,\infty]$ for all random variables, so from a logical perspective it has that advantage, but practically both offer the same amount of useful information).

Comment: but I will agree that it is nice to have definitions and theorem valid in more general situations so that we in general have to do less exceptional handling down the line. For example, in Tonelli's theorem (part of Fubini-Tonelli), it is nice to know that $\int_{X\times Y}f\,d(\mu\otimes \nu)=\int_X\int_Yf\,d\nu\,d\mu=\int_Y\int_Xf\,d\mu\,d\nu$ when $f$ is any $[0,\infty]$-valued measurable function on the product (in particular if one of these three integrals is $\infty$, so are the other two). Otherwise, one would have to work just that little bit more before applying Fubini's theorem.

Comment: I really liked this definition of variance since now I can write some propositions with fewer hypothesis.

Comment: @rfloc While I like this answer, you could get the same ability to write propositions with fewer hypotheses by using a simpler definition: define variance to be the old definition if the random variable is square integrable, and $+\infty$ otherwise.