# Var$[X]$ exists if and only if $X\in L^2$

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces

In Baldi's textbook *Probability*, he writes that a random variable $X$'s variance exists if and only if $X\in L^2(\mu)$.

I went searching through the text and cannot find where he defines what it means for a variable (rather than a function) to be in $L^2(\mu)$.  Perhaps I am just missing it, or perhaps we are supposed to assume that this means its probability density is in $L^2(\mu)$.

But if we assume that this means its density is in $L^2(\mu)$, then let $f$ be the density of $X$.  Then the variance is

$$ \text{Var}[X]=\int_{\Bbb R} (x-\mu)^2f(x) \ d\mu(x) $$

I suppose it's clear enough to me that it is possible for a function $f$ to be integrable but not $x^2f(x)$.  For instance $f(x)=1/x^2$ on $[1,\infty)$ and zero elsewhere.

But if I play the same trick with expectation, I could say that $xf(x)$ is not integrable even though $f$ is, so therefore $f\in L^1(\mu)$ does not guarantee that the expectation exists.

So my question is whether all of the above is correct: $X\in L^2(\mu)$ means its PDF is in $L^2(\mu)$, and this occurs if and only if the variance exists, but the same pattern is not true for expectation?

I found the following discussion and it echoes some of these ideas but doesn't quite answer these questions: [Why variance is only defined for square integrable random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627046/why-variance-is-only-defined-for-square-integrable-random-variables)

Comment: Two points on definitions: (1) A random variable is a function, usually from the sample space to $\mathbb{R}$, and (2) a function $f \in L^2$ means $\int (f(x))^2$ is finite, not $\int x^2f(x)$.

Comment: $X\in L^2(\mu)$ means by definition that $\int_{\Omega}|X|^2\,d\mu<\infty$.

Comment: If $X-\mu\in L_2(P)$ iff $X\in L_2(P)$ since $X=(X-\mu)+\mu$ and any constant function is square integrable w.r.t. a probability measure.

Comment: @Mittens: What if we integrated over infinite intervals?

Comment: @MSIS: the probability measure of any interval is at least $0$ and at most $1$. In any event, $\int c\,dP = c$ for any constant function $c$ ( integration is with respect to a probability measure, not with respect a measure of infinite mass).